# Reorder of Clusters Indicies of K-Means Clustering in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am using K-means Clustering.
It sometimes creates empty groups but I still wish that the group be in order.

```
 idx=kmeans(atranspose,m,'EmptyAction','drop');
 ids=unique(idx)
>> ids

ids =

     1
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    21
    22
    23
    24
    25
    26
    27
    28
    29
    30
    31
    32
    33
    34
    35
    36
    37
    38
    39
    40
    41
    42
    43
    44
    45
    46
    47
    48
    49
    50
```

I don't want 2 and 20 to be missing, instead ordered from 1 to 48. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should post some sample data for us to test with to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the unique IDs, you can remap them to new classes.

**Better New Approach**

Use the `unique` to get the new indicies.

```
% Dummy idx data
idx = [1 1 2 2 4 4 5];

% Reindexing
[~,~,newidx] = unique( idx );
```

Results

```
>> idx
idx =
     1     1     2     2     4     4     5
>> newidx'
ans =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     4
```

With a non-ascending idx

```
% Dummy idx data
idx = [1 1 2 2 4 4 5];

% Reindexing
[~,~,newidx] = unique( idx );
```

Results

```
>> idx
idx =
     2     2     1     1     4     4     5
>> newidx'
ans =
     2     2     1     1     3     3     4
```

**Slightly Longer Old Approach**

Essentially `M` is the map that maps it to the new IDs. The new mapping uses `arrayfun` to apply `M` to `idx` and stores this back into `idx`.

```
% Dummy idx data
idx = [1 1 2 2 4 4 5];

% Get unique ids
ids = unique( idx );

% Create mapping
M = containers.Map( ids, 1:length(ids) );

% Apply mapping
newidx = arrayfun( @(x) M(x), idx );
```

Results:

```
>> idx
newidx
unique( newidx )

idx =
     1     1     2     2     4     4     5
newidx =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     4
ans =
     1     2     3     4
```

If `idx` is non-ascending, you can simply `sort` after using the `unique` operator. Suppose you have the following `idx`.

```
idx = [2 2 1 1 4 4 5];
```

You can `sort` it using:

```
ids = sort( unique( idx ) );
```

After running the replaced code, you get the following result:

```
>>idx
newidx
unique( newidx )

idx =
     2     2     1     1     4     4     5
newidx =
     2     2     1     1     3     3     4
ans =
     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: I am assuming this applies to non-ascending data as well.

Comment: Well it depends, if it's not ascending, you can `sort` it after applying the `unique` operator. Is `idx` non-ascending?

Comment: Yes, it non-ascending , the cluster ids are outputed by k means algo. I am not sure if sorting is the direction I would proceed in.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia I appended my answer for the non-ascending case. Please let me know if you had a different definition of "non-ascending" and give me an example input and expected output. Otherwise kindly accepting the answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Okay what are a few of the cluster IDs and what do you want them to look like?

Comment: [2 4 2 2 4 5 6 2 2 1 1 1]= [2 3 2 2 3 4 5 2 2 1 1 1]

Comment: Great! I saw you mentioned a similar example. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Heads up that there's a quicker way using `unique` that I found. I updated my answer with results accordingly.